# how to build wso2 from platform directory

Tags: wso2, platform

I download code from github, and try to run "mvn compile" from platform, then I got following error:

D:\wso2\platform-master>mvn compile
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 4 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:carbon-dependents:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\wso2\platform-master\dependencies\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module D:\wso2\platform-master\dependencies\commons\charon\2.0.0-SNAPSHOT of D:\wso2\platform-master\dependencies\pom.xml does not e
xist
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:carbon-components:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\wso2\platform-master\components\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module D:\wso2\platform-master\components\jaggery of D:\wso2\platform-master\components\pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:carbon-features:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\wso2\platform-master\features\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module D:\wso2\platform-master\features\jaggery\features of D:\wso2\platform-master\features\pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:carbon-products:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\wso2\platform-master\products\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module D:\wso2\platform-master\products\integration\security-verifier of D:\wso2\platform-master\products\pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, you downloaded code from GitHub, I guess you cloned https://github.com/wso2/platform

WSO2 currently uses SVN as the main source repository and therefore I recommend you to use the SVN repository. Following has the current WSO2 Carbon code.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/

Before checking out the code, please make sure you understand how the SVN repository is structured.

There are many resources on the web about building WSO2 Carbon from source. Please search on the web. Here is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960940/1955702) given to a similar question about building from source.

FYI: WSO2 just released Carbon 4.2.0 and therefore we currently use the 4.2.0 branches.

- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0
- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/branches/4.2.0
- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.2.0

Comment: Yes, I download code from github.com. Got your point, I will download from svn and try again. Thanks for your guidance.